# wifi crash ubuntu 16.04 im using d-link dwa 525 adapter

Tags: wireless, adapter

sometimes my connection going down and need to disable/enable network to reconnect, so im using d-link dwa 525  adapter, i have found old driver but i have got error when i try install.   so any solution?

also im interested some wifi adapter that you have tested and works perfectly for ubuntu 16.04. thanks